# Classes in Python, string errors

Tags: python, string, class, python-2.7, object

I'm an amateur programmer in Python and got a task to finish. I've got a constant problem with getting various string errors while writing a class. That's the problematic part:

The beginning of the class, named library is written well, except from this:

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.booklist()
        print 'There are several books inside this list: ', self.howMany
        i = 1
        for book in self.booklist:
            print i
            print self.booklist[i-1]
            i += 1
```

self.booklist is a list (it's done properly)
self.howMany is the length of this list
Book is a different class.
I want to get a set of the books on the list - a number of the book on the list and the book details as given in the previous class.
The problem is the technique of writing this last part.

Comment: Not sure if you are aware, but once a function encounters a `return` statement, it stops executing. All of the lines appearing afterwards will have no effect.

Comment: but I tried doing print and I still encounter the string problem

Comment: The `__str__` function is supposed to __return__ the object's string representation, not print it. Incidentally, would your "string problem" happen to be `TypeError: __str__ returned non-string`?

Answer (score 2):

After `return self.booklist()` part, none of your codes are process. You starting your function with `return self.booklist()`, so actually your function equal to;

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.booklist()
```

Instead returning it, define a variable that take your list. You should store the `return` end of your function or in an `if-elif` statement. An example;

```
def smt():
    return "Hello"
    for x in range(5):
        print (x)
print (smt())
```

Output;

```
>>> 
Hello
>>>
```

As you see, only "Hello" printed. Codes after `return` are not processed. But if you change your function like;

```
def smt():
    a="Hello"
    for x in range(5):
        print (x)
    return a
```

Output is;

```
>>> 
0
1
2
3
4
Hello
>>>
```

You can think on some point `return` is similar to `break`. So if return part is processed somewhere in your function, it's like your function is stops reading other codes.

Comment: @esse, since you found this answer helpful, you should consider accepting it by clicking on the green check mark. That would normally give reputation points to the person who wrote it.